# Send mail using javamila API coming as undisclosed-participant <undisclosed-participant@email.invalid> in my inbox

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using below code :

```
      ic = new InitialContext();
       Session session = (Session)ic.lookup(smtpJndi); //smtpJndi I have maintained a mail session in weblogic
        dbg( "send-->lookup done"); 
Transport transport;
            transport = session.getTransport();
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom();
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailId));
            msg.setHeader("X-Priority", "1");
            msg.setSubject("Aproval Request"); 
            String htmlContent="test"
            msg.setContent(htmlContent,"text/html");
            dbg("send-->set transport.connect()");
            transport.connect(smtpHost, smtpUser, smtpPwd);
            dbg( "send-->sendMessage()");
          transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

what change should I make so that it can come with proper sender.

Answer (score 0):

The setFrom method with no arguments uses information from your environment.  If the environment doesn't have the expected information, that might cause the problem.  Try using setFrom with an explicit address:

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom("you@whatever.com");
```

Generally the From address should correspond to the account you're using on your SMTP server.